# When I run my app on Heroku, I am getting error code h10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

I want to get my app to run on Heroku. I've done it before with a different app and it worked but that was a couple months ago so I don't remember if I had the same issue then.

Once pushing the app to Heroku and attempting to run I get to the Application Error screen and it tells me to look in the logs. I check the logs and I see "Error: Cannot find module '/app/App.js'" and that the error is h10. I looked online and normally that code is for when there isn't a run script but I have one in my package file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

My App.js is located in my scr folder:

[image]

Comment: could you mention/show the set the commands used for pushing the react app to heroku ?

Comment: git add . ///

git commit --m "comment" ///

git push heroku master